# Extracting cassandra's bloom filter

Tags: java, cassandra, bloom-filter

I have a cassandra server that is queried by another service and I need to reduce the amount of queries.

My first thought was to create a bloom filter of the whole database every couple of minutes and send it to the service.
but as I have a couple of hundreds of gigabytes in the database (which is expected to grow to a couple of terabytes), it doesn't seem like a good idea overloading the database every few minutes.

After a while of searching for a better solution, I remembered that cassandra maintains its own bloom filter.

Is it possible to copy the *-Filter.db files and use them in my code instead of creating my own bloom filter?

Comment: _Queried_ how? I don't understand why you think you'd need access to its bloom filter.

Comment: I'm running cql queries from the service to cassandra. And I want to reduce the amount of queries to cassandra. Instead of creating my own bloom filter, I would like to use the built-in bloom filter in cassandra.

Comment: Why you'd want to do what cassandra already does? Your system won't be faster if you pre-filter your queries with the "same" BF. If you want to be faster you'd need to cache data (more than, or in a different way of what cassandra already does of course). IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I have Created a table test

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   a int PRIMARY KEY,
   b int
);
```

Inserted 1 row

```
INSERT INTO test(a,b) VALUES(1, 10);
```

After flush data to disk. we can use the `*-Filter.db` file. For my case it was `la-2-big-Filter.db`
Here is the sample code to check if a partition key exist

```
Murmur3Partitioner partitioner = new Murmur3Partitioner();

try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("la-2-big-Filter.db"))); IFilter filter = FilterFactory.deserialize(in, true)) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        DecoratedKey decoratedKey = partitioner.decorateKey(Int32Type.instance.decompose(i));
        if (filter.isPresent(decoratedKey)) {
            System.out.println(i + " is present ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(i + " is not present ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
1 is present 
2 is not present 
3 is not present 
4 is not present 
5 is not present 
6 is not present 
7 is not present 
8 is not present 
9 is not present 
10 is not present
```

Comment: What if the BF is still in memory and was not persisted on disk?

Comment: When memtable contents exceed a configurable threshold, the memtable data, which includes indexes, is put in a queue to be flushed to disk. You can configure the length of the queue by changing memtable_heap_space_in_mb or memtable_offheap_space_in_mb setting in the cassandra.yaml, but I think you should not change the threshold, rather you should add newly added value to your bloom filter.

Comment: Or you can use cache

Comment: This is exactly the point. If you don't have the files you cannot do anything. You need to do the same job C* already does. There is absolutely no reason to do that performance-wise. IMHO.